# MDS Error when creating a Entity Sync to an New Target Entity

Tags: master-data-services

When I try to create an Entity Sync in Master Data Services 2016, I receive the following error (fyi I chose to create a new target entity).

[image]

Not sure why this is occurring.  Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the Code attribute on the Source entity is the problem as indicated in the error message.  It needs to have its display width match its length or you will get this error.  See snip below
[image]